# How to find out what makes my PHP application to hang the Apache server?

Tags: php, apache

I am running into an issue where my PHP application hangs sometimes and the Apache server takes long to restart. Is there some way to determine what might cause this hang up?

Comment: Did you already take a look into PHP's and Apache's error-logs?

Comment: yes, you need to check access log and error logs.

Comment: `Is there some way to determine what might cause this hang up?` - yes there is. There are many ways in fact. But you will have to provide at least a *little* detail of what you *think* might be causing the problem before we can point you in the right direction. You need to provide us with logs and possibly PHP code before anyone can even hazard a guess as to what the problem might be.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Yes but they revealed nothing. Not even notices.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm not asking for a solution for this particular problem, but for a generic idea how some one would solve such issue. The only thing I can think of is to just try to pinpoint the problem but it does not always occur.

Comment: @rFactor: there is no entry inside the logs around the time the server has been crashed?

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? error_reporting(E_ALL); and 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on a linux server, a heavy solution could be to strace your Apache processes.

It will provide you with all the system calls (and parameters) done by the Apache processes, and eventually find what could be hanging (or find out that your script tries to get a resource - eg a file - that it can't read, open a socket and wait until the timeout, etc).

You invoke it like that:

strace -f -p pid

pid being the pid of the process you want to trace.

In your case, I recommend changing the configuration of your Apache server (if necessary) to have a little number of servers spawned. You fetch their pids with a regular ps command. 
Then you can strace several pids at the same time, by adding -p pid1 -p pid2 etc.
You can also use -o filename and -ff to have each process strace written to filename.pid files. Then you run your HTTP request. The process that has processed your request will be in the biggest .pid file.

Also use -s size to specify the length of text to capture, for example in 'write' syscalls, or else you might miss interesting information.

It can be hard to read, but can provide really helpful information. I use it frequently for desperate situations !