# Site keeps on hanging on Windows Azure Server

Tags: php, azure, cakephp-1.3

I have an online education site. The site is made up in WordPress and CakePHP 1.3. Recently I have migrated the site to Windows Azure server. Since then i am getting a problem. We have various portals in our site like ops portal, students portal.

All the session scheduling part is taken care of from ops portal. In the ops portal we have a "S Availability" tab that connects to a folder "bes" which is made in core php to schedule the session. Now what is happening is that after every 8- 9 clicks on this tab it starts hanging . It just keeps on processing and when I check the debug window by clicking "Inspect Element" in chrome it keeps on giving pending status to a program "ops_stu_calendar.php".

This "ops_stu_calendar" is the program that connects to "bes" folder and loads the calendar. After processing for a long time sometime it loads the calendar and sometimes I get the error:

> "500 Internal Server Error Web server cannot perform this request http://example.com/bes/calendar/ops_stu_calender?id=14996&user_type=ops" .

Also while it is processing on the bottom left of the window it keeps on giving the message "waiting for example.com". Can somebody please explain any reason for this behaviour as it is giving a lot of serious problems in our process.

Comment: Which Azure server you deployed your site on, Web app, Cloud Service or VM?

Comment: #Gary Liu It is cloud app . My site name in azure is vnayatest.cloudapp.net and the server is windows server 2012 r2

Comment: Could you provide any steps for me to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Gary Liu It is cloud app . My site name in azure is vnayatest.cloudapp.net and the server is windows server 2012 r2

Based on my understanding, cloudapp.net could refer to both Cloud Service and Virtual Machine deployed web application, it would be better if you can let us know what exactly you are using. If you are on a virtual machine deployment, in this case standard PHP troubleshooting tips apply, please make sure you are writing the logs, i.e. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php, the server logs could also help us to further troubleshoot the root cause. Additionally, this thread may provides some insights about troubleshooting hangs: [How to find out what makes my PHP application to hang the Apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033143/how-to-find-out-what-makes-my-php-application-to-hang-the-apache-server), please check it and see if it helps.

> AFter processing for a long time sometime it loads the calendar and sometimes i get the error "500 Internal Server Error Web server cannot perform this request http://example.com/bes/calendar/ops_stu_calender?id=14996&user_type=ops" .

If you are using Wordpress's All-in-One Event Calendar, it looks like there are some known browser compatibility issues: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/calendar-hangs-no-response-from-any-on-page-functions